# ScaleTransform in LayoutTransform not working but works with RenderTransform

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-4.0

I am trying to do two things in my application.

### 1. Zoom Image

Able to do with `RenderTransform`. but need to achieve in `LayoutTransform` to enable `Scrollviewer`.

### xaml

working.

```
 <Image.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}" />
 </Image.RenderTransform>
```

Not Working

```
<Image.LayoutTransform>
     <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}" />
</Image.LayoutTransform>
```

### 2. Rotate Image

works with both `ScaleTransform` and `RenderTransform` but need it with `ScaleTransform` to obtain `ScrollViewer`

Problem is in `ScaleTransform` with `LayoutTransform`

```
<Image.LayoutTransform>
    <TransformGroup> 
       <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}" />
       <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Image.LayoutTransform>
```

Not able too achieve both `ScaleTransform` and `RotateTransform` with `ScrollViewer`

I have tried with `Canvas`

### xaml

```
<Canvas.LayoutTransform>
   <TransformGroup> 
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}" />
      <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}"/>
   </TransformGroup>
</Canvas.LayoutTransform>
```

Different behavior of rotate but able to achieve both functionality working but  `ScrollViewer` not scrolling.

### Rotate Behavior for canvas

-[image]

[image]

Tried doing the same with `ViewBox`

rotate works with ScrollViewer Zoom not working.

Full Code below

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Viewbox  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
         <Viewbox.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup> 
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}" />
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Viewbox.LayoutTransform>
        <Image RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >               
            <Image.Source>                    
                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImagePath}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"></BitmapImage>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Viewbox>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Anyone can help me with suggestions.

Worked solution for me suggested by 'GazTheDestroyer'

### XAML

```
<Image RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="None" >
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                  <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}" />
                  <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}"/>
               </TransformGroup>
           </Image.LayoutTransform>
         <Image.Source>                    
           <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImagePath}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"></BitmapImage>
         </Image.Source>
 </Image>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `Stretch="None"` to your `Image` tag, or failing that supply an explicit height and width.

In certain panels WPF will automatically stretch the image to the available space in the panel, which will make your scale transform redundant when it's part of the layout process.

Comment: Long question, small answer. it worked. i will post it.