# Flip Image horizontally in itemsControls has no effect

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ItemsControl` with a `ItemsSource` of a collection of strings. These strings are path to images. I overwrote the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` to hold a Image where the `Source` is bound to the string. This works. I also want to flip the images horizontally with a `ScaleTransform`. For testing i want to flip it also vertically. But i can't get it work, both horizonally and vertically `ScaleTransform` have no effect.

**XAML**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=OverviewControlName, Path=ImagesSource}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                   Stretch="None">
                <Image.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=OverviewControlName, Path=FlipImageScaleX}"
                                    ScaleY="-1"/>
                </Image.LayoutTransform>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

ImagesSource and FlipImageScaleX are DependencyProperties. But also the hardcoded `ScaleY="-1"` has no effect.

Also using the `RenderTransform` instead of `LayoutTransform` has no effect.

I Also [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747574/scaletransform-in-layouttransform-not-working-but-works-with-rendertransform) that `Stretch="None"` takes effect of rendering the image and also of the Transforms. But also with Stretch set to none it does not work.

What am i doing wrong?

**Edit:** the images are placed in a dll as resources

Comment: Do you see any binding errors when you run with debugger attached?

Comment: By "flip" do you actually mean `RotateTransform` with an `Angle` declared? Or if you do mean `ScaleTransform` than the `Scale` would remain positive starting at 1, so for example Scale of 1 is normal size, .5 would be half sized, etc...

Comment: Are you sure your FlipImageScaleX is coming across correctly? For the most part, this works ok for me using hardcoded values of -1 or 1 for both ScaleX and/or ScaleY. And I tried it in both RenderTransform and LayoutTransform.

Comment: yes i had a binding error on the `FlipImageScaleX`, fixing the error leads to normal behaviour